# ¿Es necesario usar echo en php para responder a una solicitud Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo una duda: ¿es necesario usar `echo` en `php` para tener la respuesta de una solicitud echa por `ajax`?

Todos los ejemplos vistos son de esta manera

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="loginform" method="post">
    <div>
        Username:
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
        Password:
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />    
        <input type="submit" name="loginBtn" id="loginBtn" value="Login" />
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loginform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'login.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response)
            {
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);

                // user is logged in successfully in the back-end
                // let's redirect
                if (jsonData.success == "1")
                {
                    location.href = 'my_profile.php';
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Invalid Credentials!');
                }
           }
       });
     });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Este el `login.php`

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] && isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password']) {
    // do user authentication as per your requirements
    // ...
    // ...
    // based on successful authentication
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 1));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 0));
}
```

Me pregunto si es la única manera de lograrlo usando `echo` en `php` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respuesta corta: No.

Respuesta larga: El único requisito es que PHP genere una salida para que pueda ser enviada a AJAX, entonces, puedes usar cualquier directiva o función que genere una salida, independientemente del formato que especifiques.

Ejemplos:

```
<?php
echo 'Enviar salida al navegador';
print 'Otra salida';

$variable = 'Otro ejemplo';
?>
Esto también es una salida, pero no hay control de variables directamente
a menos que entres nuevamente en modo php <?php echo $variable; ?> y
puedes agregar más texto
<?php
// Otro ejemplo
// die() y exit() son equivalentes.
die('Envía salida y finaliza el programa');
```

Comment: bueno es una buena respuesta